# Exception : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when create new workbook Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

When i try to create new work book
An exception occured:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
Here is my code

```
Application app = new Application();
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

The error occured at the second line

```
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: just a dumb question: is there no need to declare the type of application? (like, yeah that is excel or word or whatever)

Comment: just Excel.
I have found my solution to my excel problem.